# Keep only one record with a given ID in data frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `pandas` to combine two CSV files into a single file indexed by a column called ProjectID. When this is completed there are still a number of duplicate records. I only want to keep the most recent of these (they are in date order from least to most recent). The code I have so far is:

```
merged_df = pandas.merge(df1, df2, on="ProjectID", how="left")
```

The bit I'm having trouble with is how to keep only the last row where there are more than one version of a project. Is there anything built in to `pandas` that can help with this?

**Edited to add example data**

Current data

```
ProjectID    Value    Date
1            54       9/21/2010
2            32       10/22/2010
2            32       10/28/2010
3            76       9/21/2010
4            37       9/21/2010
4            37       11/12/2010
4            38       11/14/2010
```

Wanted data

```
ProjectID    Value    Date
1            54       9/21/2010
2            32       10/28/2010
3            76       9/21/2010
4            38       11/14/2010
```

Comment: Excellent question! Could you provide us with short example data? It would greatly help in providing an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drop_duplicates` is pandas' go to function for removing duplicates from a dataframe.  By default it keeps the first observed duplicated value, but you can use the `take_last=` argument to keep the last instead.

Try: `merged_df2 = merged_df.drop_duplicates('ProjectID', take_last=True)`